# Filter multiple file types in Google picker in App Script

Tags: picker

I'm trying to create a Google sheets addon in which a file picker is displayed. I'd like to filter documents or presentations.

For some reason, the code example shown at https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#otherviews
doesn't seem to work, and I'm using the same syntax

Only Documents are pre-filtered using the code below, and not Documents + Presentations.

```
var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            .addViewGroup(new google.picker.ViewGroup(google.picker.ViewId.DOCUMENTS)
               .addView(google.picker.ViewId.PRESENTATIONS))

            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
            .hideTitleBar()
            .setOAuthToken(token)
            .setDeveloperKey(DEVELOPER_KEY)
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
            .setSize(DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.width - 2, DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.height - 2)
            .build();
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Trying to clarify: .addViewGroup(new google.picker.ViewGroup(google.picker.ViewId.PRESENTATIONS).addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCUMENTS))    should filter on presentations and documents. It only filters on presentations. How can I fix that please?

Answer (score 0):

If more than one view is added to the Google Picker, users switch from one view to another by clicking a tab on the left. Tabs can be logically grouped with ViewGroup objects.

Comment: So you have to click on "Google Drive" to see it.